# DbgPrint output differs form the output of Macro to DbgPrint

Tags: c, wdk

I defined a macro to DbgPrint to prints message when the _DEBUG defined

```
#define MYDBGPRINT(X) #ifdef _DEBUG \
    DbgPrint(X) \
#endif
```

but the output is differ from the DbgPrint for example

```
ULONG id=0;
MYDBGPRINT("the value of the id : %u ",id)  //outputs garbage
DbgPrint("the value of the id : %u ",id)  //outputs the correct value of id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the pre-processor to create pre-processor definitions. I've never tried that myself, but it seems like a bad idea that probably won't work. Instead try something like:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define MYDBGPRINT(X) DbgPrint(X)
#else
#define MYDBGPRINT(X)
#endif
```

or in the case of having a variable number of arguments to your macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MYDBGPRINT(...) DbgPrint(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define MYDBGPRINT(...)
#endif
```

Comment: Note that the __VA_ARGS__ method may be compiler specific. I've used it with GCC but I'm unsure if it works with Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: the second solution is ok. i must use the variadic Macros  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro